# Google Cloud FUSE with Cloud Run [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/database' but already granted Storage Object Admin access

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I am using GCP's Cloud FUSE together with Cloud Run, as outlined in this tutorial by google (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-fuse#cloudrun_fs_code-python). However, after I deployed the app, the app is not able to access that folder but instead got this error in the log `[Errno 5] Input/output error: '/database'` , where 'database' is the folder name From what I read online, this is usually due to not having sufficient permission. However, I checked the dashboard at Cloud FUSE and I have already granted Storage Object Admin access to the service account of the app.

The app is written in python 3.9. I am not able to perform `os.listdir('/database')`. However, when I used `os.listdir('/')`, 'database' is one of the items on the list, and `os.path.isdir('/database')` returns true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me why you're looking for `/database`.

Did you deploy by `--update-env-vars=MNT_DIR=/database,BUCKET=...`?

The app defaults to `MNT_DIR=/mnt/gcs` as this is set in `gcsfuse.Dockerfile`

Where does the `[Errno 5]` error originate?

I deployed the code as-is from the tutorial and it works for me.

It uses `/mnt/gcs` (surfaced through the Cloud Run endpoint url +`/mnt/gcs`.

Files are created upon refresh and these are visible in the GCS bucket.

###### Update

Here's my end-to-end script:

```sh
Q=70354313

BILLING="..." # Your Billing Account
PROJECT="$(whoami)-$(date +%y%m%d)-${Q}" # Or ...
BUCKET="$(whoami)-$(date +%y%m%d)-${Q}" # Or ...
REGION="us-west1" # Or ...

NAME="stackoverflow"

MNT_DIR="/database"

ACCOUNT="stackoverflow"
EMAIL="${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples.git
cd python-docs-samples/run/filesystem/

# Use FUSE not Filestore
rm Dockerfile 
cp gcsfuse.Dockerfile Dockerfile

# GCP stuff
gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}

gcloud beta billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}

SERVICES=(
    "artifactregistry"
    "cloudbuild"
    "run"
)
for SERVICE in ${SERVICES[@]}
do
  gcloud services enable ${SERVICE}.googleapis.com \
  --project=${PROJECT}
done

# Create GCS Bucket
gsutil mb -l ${REGION} -p ${PROJECT} gs://${BUCKET}

# Create Service Account
gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=roles/storage.objectAdmin

gcloud beta run deploy ${NAME} \
--source=${PWD} \
--execution-environment=gen2 \
--allow-unauthenticated \
--service-account=${ACCOUNT} \
--update-env-vars=MT_DIR=${MNT_DIR},BUCKET=${BUCKET} \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Then:

```sh
ENDPOINT=$(\
  gcloud run services describe ${NAME} \
  --region=${REGION} \
  --platform=managed \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(status.url)") && echo ${ENDPOINT}

# Curl the Cloud Run service endpoint 5 times
for test in {1..5}
do
  curl \
  --silent \
  --location \
  --output /dev/null \
  --write-out "%{response_code}\n" \
  ${ENDPOINT}
  # Files are only differentiated at minute accuracy
  sleep 60s
done

# Enumerate the GCS Bucket
gsutil ls gs://${BUCKET}
```

Comment: Yes I set `MNT_DIR`as `/database`. `[Errno 5]` occurs when I try to access files or folders inside `/database`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. When your write "access", do you mean "when you browse the Cloud Run service endpoint"? Are you definitely running the Cloud Run service as the Service Account? You can `gcloud iam service-accounts list --project=${PROJECT}` and you can confirm the Service Account is being applied with (from memory) `gcloud run services describe ${NAME} --region=${REGION} --platform=managed --project=${PROJECT} --format="value(spec.template.spec.ServiceAccountName)"`

Comment: I guess, another question|proposal is, what happens if you don't override the default value of `MNT_DIR`?

Comment: when I run `gcloud iam service-accounts list --project=${PROJECT}`, it lists the account I intended to use (among other ones). When I run `gcloud run services describe ${NAME} --region=${REGION} --platform=managed --project=${PROJECT} --format="value(spec.template.spec.ServiceAccountName)", it returns an empty new line

Comment: I'll try to repro your issue this morning. I've got some other stuff to get done first thing but I'll get to it this (my) morning.

Comment: I noticed a typo in my  suggested command, it should be `serviceAccountName` not `ServiceAccountName`

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by mounting fuse at the directory `/mnt/gcs` instead.

Comment: I just reran the scripts using `/database` and it works for me. I've been unable to get it to **not** work. I'll post my script in my answer and perhaps you'll see where your issue arose.